# import packages in Python

Tags: python, import

I copied a package in `Lib\site-packages` to the same folder in another PC.

Then, I tried to import that package.

```
import xxx
```

But I received the error of `No module named xxx`.

How to solve this problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: This is not enough description of your problem. Please elaborate.

Comment: you haven't that module installed in another PC

Comment: you need to install/copy other dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the same Python version on both PCs, you can just copy the content of Lib\site-packages and Scripts to the new one. But note that it must be the same minor version (e.g. 2.6 does not work with 2.7).

Another way is if you use a virtualenv (http://www.virtualenv.org) you should be able to store that on a USB-stick and carry it with you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to copy the egg-info or dist-info as well.

Your library path may also be wrong. On my machine with Ubuntu 16.04, the default local path is '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages'.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an environment variable called "PYTHONPATH" and then input the path of your packages.